# Suppose a function $f:R\to R$ has a bounded derivative, then is the function itself bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose a function $f:R\to R$ has a bounded derivative, then is the function itself bounded? Is the function then lipschitz continuous? Is every lipschitz function bounded?

Comment: Have you thought through any examples? Some of the first functions you learn to differentiate will answer the first and third questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any function with bounded derivative is Lipschitz continuos.

Let $|f'| \leq L$, with $L >0$ a constant. Then $\forall x,y$
$$|f(x) - f(y)| = |f'( \xi) (x-y)| \leq L|x-y|$$
where $\xi$ is an intermediate value given by the MVT.

However, you cannot say that $f$ is bounded. Take as a counterexample $f(x) = x$.